# How to install openpyxl within IronPython

Tags: ironpython, openpyxl

I was trying to install openpyxl using the setup.py which in turn uses setuptools. Unfortunately, setuptools cannot be installed within IronPython and I would like to know what other options exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it directly from: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/default/ and include it on your python path.

Comment: That seems to be a restricted or private repository.