# Python module imports Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, ironpython, openpyxl

I have installed openpyxl. Working through the examples in Idle, I encounter no issues.

Trying to use my VisualStudio python editor, module imports fail.

Does openpyxl need to be added to IronPython for this to work? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980785/how-to-install-openpyxl-within-ironpython

Comment: Looking at the comments on here, I'll maybe leave this for now anyway: https://ericgazoni.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/openpyxl-1-6-6/

Comment: If is is possible to use the CPython implementation but do my editing in VisualStudio, that would be useful though.

Comment: would you like to point it as a solution for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openpyxl does not work with IronPython. But that should not affect using it with VisualStudio. Presumably you need to set the path for the project.

Comment: Found the option in Visual Studio to set C Python as default rather than IronPython and can now utilise openpyxl.